# How to change font family of text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Here is the JS code it results in animation like handwriting, I want to change font family. I have tried a lot to change it but failed. I have added link of font family from Google and added in a head section. How can I change font family?

```
<script>
    var fontsize = 72;
        if (window.screen.width > 700)
            fontSize=50;else if (window.screen.width > 1200)
                fontSize = 90;
            var vara = new Vara(
                "#container-animation",
                "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akzhy/Vara/master/fonts/Satisfy/SatisfySL.json",
            [
            {
                text : "Laser",
                y : 150,
                fromCurrentPosition: {y:false},
                duration:6000,
            },
            {
                text : "Lorem Ipsum",
                y : 150,
                fromCurrentPosition: {y:false},
                delay:3000,
                duration:3000
            },
            {
                text : "Whole-food, quality recipes you can easily make at home",
                y : 150,
                fromCurrentPosition: {y:false},
                delay:3000,
                duration:4500
            },
            ],
            {
                strokeWidth: 2,
                fontSize:fontSize,
                color: "#fff",
                textAlign:"center"
            }
            );

        vara.ready(function(){
            var erase= true;
            vara.animationEnd(function(i, o){
                if (i=="no_erase") erase = false;
                if(erase) {
                    o.container.style.transition = "opacity 1s 1s";
                    o.container.style.opacity = 0;
                }
            });
            })
</script>
```

Comment: *"I have tried alot to change it but failed"* says nothing about the issue you're facing. *"I need urgent help"* - you'll get one if you create a [mcve] and explain exactly: what's the problem you're experiencing and what's the desired output.

Comment: Hi Ramsha, try Google 'javascript change fontFamily', could not be easier. Here's one example [w3schools: Style fontFamily Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontfamily.asp).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: To be able to give a proper/full answer, you need to post a [reprex] as now we can only guess what code/variable is used to change the 'font-family'. What is 'Vara'?? As I understand 'Vara' has it's own font style (made with SVG paths) and cannot be changed... Checkout: [Vara font-creator](http://vara.akzhy.com/font-creator/)

Comment: Hard to follow with your current indentation...

Answer (score 2):

Here a simple function that takes 2 parameters:

- element selection criterium (id, class, etc.) as string
- fontFamily string

All elements selected will get their `font-family` set to the passed string (or default 'Arial,Helvectia,sans-serif' when fontFamily string is undefined)...

```html
<script>
function changeFontFamily(selString,fontString) {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll(selString); // list of elements
       // if elements exists and if fontstring defined then change, otherwise add some default value; 
       element.forEach( function(e,idx) { e.style.fontFamily = (fontString) ? fontString : 'Arial,Helvetica,sans- serif'; });
    }
</script>

<!-- change font-family of classes .test1 and .test2 -->
<div onclick="changeFontFamily('.test1,.test2','monospace');">
    <div>
        <div class="test1">test 1.1</div>
        <div class="test1">test 1.2</div>
        <div class="test2">test 2.1</div>
        <div class="test2">test 2.2</div>
        <div class="test2">test 2.3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actualyy I want to add font family in the same code. Like I want to change thes text section, whatever in this text change its font family  
 {
                text : "Lorem Ipsum",
                y : 150,
                fromCurrentPosition: {y:false},
                delay:3000,
                duration:3000
            },

Comment: similarly :   {
                text : "Laser",
                y : 150,
                fromCurrentPosition: {y:false},
                duration:6000,
            },

in it I want to change font family of "Laser"