# How do you adjust the font and font family on this date script

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to add a font: Arial and color: White to this script?

```
<script>
            var date = new Date();
            days_change = -2;
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + days_change);
    
            const formattedDate = date.toLocaleString("en-GB", {
                day: "numeric",
                month: "long",
                year: "numeric",
            });
    
            document.write(formattedDate);
</script>
```

Comment: If you add the output to an HTML element then append it to the DOM, you could use CSS to style the text, yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change font family of text in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850559/how-to-change-font-family-of-text-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another solution.

You can wrap **formattedDate** in a `<span>...</span>` tag with a class. As here:

```
document.write("<span class='date_arial'>" + formattedDate + "</span>");
```

And add the desired styles to the CSS. As here:

```
.date_arial {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```js
var date = new Date();
            days_change = -2;
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + days_change);
    
            const formattedDate = date.toLocaleString("en-GB", {
                day: "numeric",
                month: "long",
                year: "numeric",
            });
 
            document.write(formattedDate);
            
            document.write("<span class='date_arial'>" + formattedDate + "</span>");
```

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.date_arial {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```